# while statment adding txt to php page

Tags: php

I have this issue where "" quotes are getting added into my page at a particular point as seen below.

[image]

this is the code in that area.. but im just not sure whats doing it.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['width'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" /><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Delete" /></form></td>"';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

any help would be hugely appreciated! this is driving me abit loopy!

Comment: Try putting `<form>` tag out the while loop and end it after `</table>`

Comment: @asprin, that isn't the problem. That line that echo's the form, starts with an single quote, but at the ends, there is an double quote, and then the single quote that ends the echo statement...

Comment: @Vijay Verma had the better answer.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 14):

This line:

```
echo '<td><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" /><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Delete" /></form></td>"';
```

had on the end the "

because you start it with an singel qoute.. so take that one away, and the problem is solved...

Comment: oh man.. I have just spent an hour trying all sorts of crap to sort that!!!

Comment: @HurkNburkS btw try not to echo too much of html

Comment: @HurkNburkS haha, know the feeling ;-) The best thing is to be constant at this thing. I recommend to use the single qoute most of the time, so you can use the double qoute for the html ellements ;-)

Comment: oh right cool.. will keep that in mind. @Mr. Alien, how else can i get the html onto the view? <?php ?> sorta thing?

Comment: yup.. kinda like this `<tag><?php //here goes the code ?></tag>`

Comment: @HurkNburkS, no problem ;-) And the best way is to store it in an variable, and when you make up the website thourgh the template, echo the variable (where all the html tags are stored in)